# Handle listview OnItemClick events in service

Tags: android, android-listview, android-service, onclicklistener

I have encountered a problem in android programming where I need to have a listview created from a service, The listview works fine and displays items as expected. The only issue is that I cannot handle item click events on the listview. I have tried to google and figure out a way but unsuccessfully.  How can I solve this problem? Below is my code,

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class ContactsService extends Service implements OnClickListener,
 OnItemClickListener {


 private WindowManager mWindowManager;
 private View mChatHead;
 private LinearLayout mLayout, chatheadcontacts;


 private TextView hidetextView;
 private ImageView showView, cameraImageView;


 ListView contacts;
 public ArrayList<ContactListItem> contactsList;
    LayoutInflater inflater;


 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
 return null;
 }


 // @SuppressLint("NewApi")
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
 super.onCreate();


 // Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
 // "Roboto-Light.ttf");


 mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
 Display display = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
 /*
 * Point size = new Point(); display.getSize(size); screenWidth =
 * size.x; screenHeight = size.y;
 */


 inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
 mChatHead = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chathead, null);
 contacts = (ListView) mChatHead
 .findViewById(R.id.listView_chathead_contacts);
 mLayout = (LinearLayout) mChatHead
 .findViewById(R.id.chathead_linearlayout);


 chatheadcontacts = (LinearLayout) mChatHead
 .findViewById(R.id.chathead_contacts_layout);


        cameraImageView = (ImageView)mChatHead.findViewById(R.id.chathead_imageView_camera);
 hidetextView = (TextView) mChatHead.findViewById(R.id.textViewhide);
 showView = (ImageView) mChatHead.findViewById(R.id.imageViewShow);


 // mChatHeadTextView.setTypeface(tf);


 contactsList = new ArrayList<ContactListItem>();
 contactsList = getContacts();
 final WindowManager.LayoutParams parameters = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
 WRAP_CONTENT, // Width
 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, // Height
 TYPE_PHONE, // Type
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
 | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, // Flag
 PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT // Format
 );


 parameters.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;


 contacts.setAdapter(new CustomChatheadListAdapter(getBaseContext(),
 contactsList));
 mWindowManager.addView(mChatHead, parameters);
 chatheadcontacts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 hidetextView.setOnClickListener(this);
 showView.setOnClickListener(this);
 contacts.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        cameraImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
 }
@Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
 long id) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
 .show();


        Log.i("Clicked",""+position);
 // showPopup();
 }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure the ListView item View does not contain any focusable View like Button.

Comment: If I get what you mean, each listview item has an imageview only.

Answer (score 0):

In your `activity`, declare and reference your listview instead of implementing `onItemClickListener` directly.

Then, try the following code

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position){

ItemClicked item = adapter.getItem(position);

// do your action

}


});
```

in your adapter's `getItem` you write

```
public ItemClicked getItem(int position){

return items.get(position);
}
```

Comment: Your code has syntax errors here ItemClicked item = adapter.getItem(position);